# ValueError: The 'ahk' package was not installed in a way that PackageLoader understands

Tags: python, exe, autohotkey, valueerror, site-packages

First and Foremost thank you to whomever can help me. I love Stackoverflow and couldn't imagine living without it as a Developer.

My problem:
I built an AutoHotKey Script inside Python, so I can get a GUI in front of it. The script works awesome. The issue is, when I compile it to an .exe through python. I receive the message below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxbgl.png)

Text of issue:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.pyw", line 14, in 
ahk = AHK()
^^^^^
File "ahk_sync\engine.py", line 130, in **init**
File "ahk_sync\transport.py", line 610, in **init**
File "jinja2\loaders.py", line 323, in **init**
ValueError: The 'ahk' package was not installed in a way that PackageLoader understands.

---

Troubleshooting I've done:
-Uninstalled & reinstall: VSCODE, PYTHON, and AutoHotKey multple times.
-Doublechecked that I had the latest versions of all 3
-Tried different Autohotkey modules
-Added all folder paths to the System Environment on my PC
-Employed ChatGPT to help
-Employeed Youtube
-checked site-packages

All the above have not granted me a solution.
What I am expecting is to run the .exe with no issues. I don't want to have to open VSCODE everytime I want to run my script.

Please help! Thank you :)

Comment: Does your app use `jinja`?

Comment: Hi Michael. No, I don't believe so.

Comment: `python -m pip freeze` will output a list of installed packages. Please verify that `jinja` isn't in that output.

Comment: Thank you, Michael.  I didn't know about this command. Here is the list.  It looks like it is on there.

Answer (score 0):

`ahk` author here. This issue should now be resolved in [v1.1.3](https://github.com/spyoungtech/ahk/releases/tag/v1.1.3).

Basically, if you package `ahk` as a dependency into a frozen/compiled app, many tools used for freezing Python apps don't automatically include package data needed for normal functionality. This can usually be resolved through a proper configuration in building/freezing your app, but to make this easier for users, in v1.0.0, we introduced a fallback mechanism for these cases, but until 1.1.3, this mechanism was not working correctly.